# How to config drone to fail the Playwright pipeline only on any error on a specific browser

Tags: testing, playwright, drone.io

I have a drone pipeline that runs some Playwright tests.
I also configured the Playwright to run the tests on 3 different browsers.

But I want it to only fail the pipeline when a test fails on chrome, not on the other 2 browsers, I mean if any test fails on that 2 browsers, just show the error message and not fail the pipeline.

Does anybody have such experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem by creating 2 different "playwright.config.ts" files.

The 1st file uses the 1st set of browsers and the 2nd file uses the 2nd set of browsers.

**Playwright.browser1.config.ts**

```
...
use {
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
    },
  ],
}
```

**Playwright.browser2.config.ts**

```
...
use {
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] },
    },
  ],
}
```

Then I divided the playwright test pipeline into 2 different pipelines in the drone config file.

**.drone.yml**

```
- name: 'E2E Tests on the 1st set of browsers'
  commands:
  - yarn playwright test --config=playwright.browser1.config.ts
...other related configs

- name: 'E2E Tests on the 2nd set of browsers'
failure: ignore
  commands:
  - yarn playwright test --config=playwright.browser2.config.ts
...other related configs
```